# I'm using express js, mongoose, and ember js. Is there a way to write models only once?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ember.js, express, mongoose

I know [Integrating Ember with Express JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720791/integrating-ember-with-express-js) says that you generally should have two representations of your models (one in backbone, one in express using mongoose schema), but I was wondering if there is some way to define a model once and have it translated into an ember model and a mongoose model on the fly.

I really don't want to repeat myself in code by writing the same model twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that you can do this is by building a generator. I am currently looking into this using noeo4js as the back end, you can either read the ember model, and generate it based on its information or generate a ember model based on your backend's model, or generate both of a descriptor json object.